# Mouse goes crazy in any game that requires mouse input

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, mouse

I have been gaming recently on my computer. Whenever I move in games like TF2 and Minecraft, and then move the mouse the camera goes crazy.

If I don't move or interact with the world, then the mouse works fine. This also happens with games that use Unity Web Player, except with Unity it is much worse. The game doesn't take any mouse or keyboard input and is focused.

Mouse : Logitech VX Revolution
Keyboard : Logitech K120

I have done countless hours Google searching, and this kid has the exact same problems as I have. Here is a link to his video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g96j-KjYAzI

Please note, I am also not a very tech forward guy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interrupt issue. Each attached device interrupts the computer to say it's done something. Some devices share an interrupt (IRQ). Go to computer manager-> device manager ->view menu -> resources by connection-> interrupt request. See if you can move the mouse and/or keyboard to another IRQ.

Comment: I cant find that option anywhere in 8.1

Comment: Open your folders, so that you can see "computer" (or what ever you named it) right click on it and select manage.

Comment: I did that but I still can't find the interrupt request thing.

Comment: Sorry missed a step, edited original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain for those particular games but I do know of another that suffers from this issue, Second Life.
It could possibly be cause by having your screen set to something other than 100% zoom - many machines seem to default to 125%.

You need the Display Control Panel. One way to get there is right click your desktop & select Screen Resolution, at the bottom of that panel is "make text & other items larger or smaller". Clicking that brings you to Display. Make sure it's set to 100%.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but my machine is one that I built myself with help from youtube, and is already set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several mice with this problem and it took me a VERY long time to figure out exactly what the problem was (and I do consider myself tech 'forward'). First, your problem may simply be due to wireless issues. If your mouse is wireless then ensure you have a good charge and try switching it to a different channel a few times. If this doesn't fix it then your problem is probably the same as mine and this is due to you overloading your USB bus. The cause for this could be any number of devices you may have attached to you USB bus. Since you'll probably want to keep most of them like I did, I'll tell you the solutions which worked for me in order of preference.

My motherboard actually has two USB controllers. I moved everything except the mouse to the other controller and the problem went away. This is how I knew that the problem was simply too much on the bus.

If you don't have two USB controllers then you may be able to fix this by adjusting your mouse driver settings. Many mice support multiple polling speeds and resolutions.

Getting another USB hub WILL NOT fix this (and may actually make it a little worse) so don't bother. If you want to go the hardware route you'd need a USB controller (which is a PCI device you'd put inside your PC).

A final option would be to replace your mouse with one which is made better. Gaming mice actually tend to be worse at this than standard mice so get a good standard mouse and you'll be good. I suggest something which uses the [Logitech unifying receiver](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/promotions/6072) because that is very handy as well as friendly for the USB bus (esp if you go with a wireless keyboard later).

Comment: I did find a wireless keyboard/mouse duo at TigerDirect and bought it. That didn't change anything.